# How to deploy a wiremock service from a spring boot application to azure app services?

Tags: spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, wiremock

I have a spring-boot application in which I start a wiremock server on localhost, port 80. When I run the application locally, I can access the wiremock server (on http://localhost:80). However, when the spring-boot application is deployed to app services in azure and started, the 80 port is already used, so the mock cannot start.

The ideea is to have the application deployed and the mock started, so when I access the URL of the app service, to be able to access the mock.

I have tried changing the port and I can see from the logs that the mock starts on other ports. However, when accessing the URL of the app service, it does not redirect to the mock. The spring-boot is not a web application, so it should not take the default port 80 and leave it unoccupied instead. I am new to azure app services and spring-boot, so any advice would be apreciated

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MocksApplication.class, args);      
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }   

    private void startMock() {

        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("mock").getFile());
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        mock= new WireMockServer((wireMockConfig().usingFilesUnderDirectory(path).port(80)));
        mock.start();
        logger.info("Starting mock on port " + mock.port() + " and bind addresss: " + mock.baseUrl());

    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        startMock();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get started by visiting the Azure for Java developers page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure

The following example, will guide you to run a Spring-boot application on Azure App Service Linux:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin

Probably in your example, you just needed to define an appsetting JAVA_OPTS witht the following value to force your app to start in port 80:

> -Dserver.port=80

App Service Linux will try to automatically detect the port that your app is using but if you start in a non-conventional port, you can also specify an app setting called WEBSITES_PORT and give it the value of the expected port number.

Additionally, please check the documentation for configuration guide for Java apps on App Service
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/configure-language-java

Also, the App Service Linux FAQ
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq